# change margin in newenvironment

Tags: macros, environments

I have a new environment defined as

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize}
\titlelabel{\bfseries \thetitle.\quad }

 \newenvironment{ans}[1][Ans]
{   
    { \it #1\ }:\ 
}

\begin{document}    
    \title{Title}
    \author{SL} 
    \maketitle
    \section{Prove that a finite subgroup ....}
    \begin{ans} Let $F$ be a field and $G ...
    \end{ans}   
\end{document}
```

It produces answer that does not align with the question as follows.

[image: wrong alignment]

I would like to align the answer to the question. How do it do it?

Comment: Why do you use sections for that? Would it be okay for you to use enumeration?

Comment: @TeXnician yes I used enumeration in my previous assignment. I thought it was a hassle since I would have inner enumeration inside enumeration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting in an `adjustwidth` environment, from `changepage` leads  to a solution. Another solution consists in using `ntheorem` to define a `\theoremindent`. If you want an end-of-environment symbol, it can place it automatically:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec, changepage, lipsum}

\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremindent = 2.05em
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{\upshape\ :\ }
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
\newtheorem{varans}{Ans.}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize}
\titlelabel{\bfseries \thetitle.\quad }

 \newenvironment{ans}[1][Ans]
{\begin{adjustwidth}{2.05em}{} \hangafter =1\par
    { \itshape #1\ }:\ }{\end{adjustwidth}\medskip}

    \title{Title}
    \author{SL}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \section{Prove that a finite subgroup ....}
    \begin{ans} Let $F$ be a field and $G $ ... \lipsum[11]
    \end{ans}

\lipsum[1]
    \section{Prove that a finite subgroup ....}
    \begin{varans} Let $F$ be a field and $G $ ... Blah blah blah. 
    \end{varans}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for teaching something new. I didn't know you could begin new environment while defining new environment.

Comment: I believe the fully correct syntax would be to use the lower level pair `\adjustwidth … \endadjustwidth`, but here the highest level works. Note the alignment will be problematic if the section numbers have more than one digit (unless you put the section numbers in the margin, with the advanced interface of `titlesec`).

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do it with an enumeration:

[image: right alignment]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

 \newenvironment{ans}[1][Ans]
{   
    \\ { \it #1\ }:\ 
}

\begin{document}    
    \title{Title}
    \author{SL} 
    \maketitle
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Prove that a finite subgroup ....
            \begin{ans}
                Let $F$ be a field and $G$ ...
            \end{ans}   
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

*Update:* To have bold enumeration labels use package `enumitem` and `\setlist[enumerate]{label=\textbf{\arabic*})}`.